# Help with textbook formula

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions

In [Bishop - Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~banmi/elte/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20and%20Machine%20Learning.pdf), Section 1, I do not fully understand Formula (1.65). Although it's not stated explicitly, I assume that **I** is the identity matrix with the dimensions M x M. If I insert the two parameters into the formula for the normal distribution I cannot get to the expression as stated in (1.65).

My current attempt looks as follows [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apm8ua90qohveqk/PBML-1.65.png?dl=0) -- sorry for the Dropbox link, I don't habe enough reputation yet. And here is where I got stuck. I have no idea how to get from the notion of the identity matrix to M as part of the exponent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Comment: The first expression in the attempt is for the univariate case with variance replaced by $\alpha^{-1} I$. For multivariate case, pdf has a slightly [different form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Non-degenerate_case).